# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}<\infty$ for some $1<p<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{q}<\infty$ for any $q>p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the question asked in CSIR NET exam,
Let $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ be an arbitrary sequence of real numbers. Then

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}<\infty$ for some $1<p<\infty$
   implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{q}<\infty$ for any $q>p$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}<\infty$ for some $1<p<\infty$
   implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{q}<\infty$ for any $1 \leq q<p$
3. Given any $1<p<q<\infty$, there is a real sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}<\infty$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{q}=\infty$
4. Given any $1<q<p<\infty$, there is a real sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{p}<\infty$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{q}=\infty$

For 2 nd option I consider
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}} \text { and } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ so this is incorrect.

Fourth we can construct such sequence
$\left(a_{n}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/q}}\right)^{q}$.

what about the statement $1$ and $3$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it is a counting measure, $\ell^p \subsetneq \ell^q, \forall 1 \le p < q \le \infty$

Answer (score 4):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_{n}|^p$ converges then $|x_{n}|^p$ converges to $0$. So for $\epsilon=1$ you can find $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geqslant k$ : $1>|x_{n}|^p>|x_{n}|^q$ as $q>p$. By comparison test $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} |x_{n}|^p>\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} |x_{n}|^q$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_{n}|^q$ converges.
The third options contradicts the first one.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

- For 1, remember that if $\sum |x_n|^p < + \infty$, then $|x_n| \to 0$ and in particular $|x_n| < 1$ for $n$ large enough, and then $|x_n|^q < \cdots$.
- For 3, use 1.
- For 4, you may have a small typo in the sequence you consider. However, taking a power sequence seems like a good idea. If you look at $x_n = 1/n^{\alpha}$, what would you like about $\alpha$?